# How to deal with "Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use Bootstrap 3 and jquery to load an editable table into HTML but for some reason, I am constantly getting the Uncaught typeerror even though I am loading all modules, and I am having no issues running the file in jsfiddle but not on here.
http://jsfiddle.net/6o3c9e4p/1/

[image]
[image]

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"  cellspacing="0" id="mainTable" data-click-to-select="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-pagination="true">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="storeName" data-halign="center" data-align="left" data-sortable="true">Store Name</th>

        <th data-field="sales" data-halign="center" data-align="left" data-sortable="true" data-editable="true">Sales</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>

</table>

    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

script.js - Javascript+jQuery 2.1.0

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
$.fn.editable.defaults.container = 'body';

var data = [{storeName: 'A',  sales: 'na'},
           {storeName: 'B',  sales: 'na'},
           {storeName: 'C', sales: 'na'},
           {storeName: 'D', sales: 'na'}
           ]

$('table').bootstrapTable({
    data: data,
    sortable: true,
    resizable: true,
    editable: true
});


$('.editable').click(function(){
    if($(this).next('.editable-container').width() > $(this).closest('td').width()){
        $('th:eq('+$(this).closest('td').index()+')').css('width', $(this).next('.editable-container').width()+15);
    }
});

$('.editable').on('hidden', function() {
    $('th:eq('+$(this).closest('td').index()+')').css('width', 'auto'); 
});
```

Comment: `$.fn.editable`  looks like your not loading some plugin, maybe called `editable`

Comment: Look at your fiddle, it's loading a lot more than just jquery & bootstrap..

Comment: @Keith I have tried using these plugins, but they don't work as well           
 <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>

Comment: As @keith has confirmed, your fiddle includes many more 3rd party includes than the example code you've provided in the question.  Click on *Resources* on the left of the filddle page and include all of those scripts in your own page.